# NX: 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead

Tags: reactjs, nrwl-nx

Working a NX project and while there are no problems in VSCode's Problems tab while doing React work, when I goto open any *.spec.tsx file I get slammed with many of the same errors:
'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
I've read and attempted implementation of many posts around this - both SO and GitHub threads. Nothing is working and I do believe it is something todo with NX. Tests run fine w/o import, but to get lit up with loads of the same error upon opening any spec file that doesn't have a React import is very frustrating. Any insight greatly appreaciated. I did also try adding the global access to UMD setting in my jest config. My .babelrc just has this and I think it may be where the problem lies.

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@nrwl/react/babel",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic",
        "useBuiltIns": "usage"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": []
}
```